# How do I access The URL shared over an Activity Sheet in iOs

Tags: swift, pdf, import, ios-sharesheet

I am trying to import a PDF to my App through Safari via activity sheet. My app pops up on the activity sheet but I cannot access the URL.
I have tried using the application(_:open:options:) function in my app delegate but it's not working
[url handling function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s35En.png)

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication,
   open url: URL,
   options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool{

    print(url)
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution here [Using Scene Delegate Functions To Receive Urls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59076416/url-opening-swift-app-open-works-called-function-does-not-work/59286428#59286428)

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, openURLContexts URLContexts: Set<UIOpenURLContext>) {
print(URLContexts.debugDescription)
```

}